# Compare one column value between row number 1 and row number 2

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following table `basket` for example.

```
basket fruit   quantity
1      mango   2
1      apple   2
2      banana  2
2      banana  3
2      banana  3
```

Now I have to find the baskets which have more than 1 row and in the basket the types are different to each other. So basket number 1 should come out.

I have written the following SQL:

```
select count(*),c.basket from baskets c group by c.basket having count(*)>1;
```

But after this how can I get the baskets where the fruit types are different to each other among the rows? It should be basket number 1 in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add to the `HAVING` clause:

```
select count(*), c.basket 
  from baskets c 
 group by c.basket 
having count(*)>1 
   AND COUNT(DISTINCT fruit)>1;
```

Comment: Just FYI, you don't need the first part of the `HAVING` filter

Comment: Yes, of course, having multiple different fruits in one's basket implies that is more than one thing in the basked. I tried to show how to have multiple conditions in the having clause.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `min()` and `max()`:

```
select b.basket
from baskets b
group by b.basket
where min(b.fruit) <> max(b.fruit);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `exists` :

```
select b.*
from baskets b
where exists (select 1 
              from baskets b1 
              where b1.basket = b.basket and 
                    b1.fruit <> b.fruit
            );
```